# What's wrong with my code? Why do I have an error?

Tags: java, syntax-error, runtime-error

So I'm using this code to sort a number array but it gives me an error that I need a "}".
Am I missing some "}"?
Any help would be appreciated!

```
double Median()
{
    int k,Hide;

    boolean IsThereASwap;
    IsThereASwap = false;

    while(IsThereASwap == false )
    {
        for ( k = 0 ; k < TheArrayAssingment.length - 1; k++)
        {
            if( TheArrayAssingment[k] > TheArrayAssingment[k+1] )
            {
                Hide = TheArrayAssingment[k+1];
                TheArrayAssingment[k+1] = TheArrayAssingment[k];
                TheArrayAssingment[k]   = Hide;
                IsThereASwap = true;
            }
        }
        if ( IsThereASwap == true)
        {
            IsThereASwap = false;
        }
        else
        {
            IsThereASwap = true;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Well... what line is it complaining about?

Comment: Also, try to avoid pasting tabs into the code blocks. They tend to screw up the formatting.

Comment: `!IsThereASwap` and `IsThereASwap = !IsThereASwap`... but consider using normal Java naming conventions. And indenting a bit more consistently. But w/o the rest of the code, tough to say.

Comment: It doesn't say. All it says is "error: missing return statement
 }"

Comment: Well that's a totally different error, isn't it--and it's true, you don't return anything from a method declared to return a double.

Comment: Then add a [return statement](http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=280)...

Comment: you should have posted the exact error message, you posted what you thought you saw, not what was actually there.

Comment: Totally whack code.  Is this an array of booleans?  Your code is wrong is so many ways.

Comment: @duffymo then help him. patronizing doesnt solve anything.

Comment: I think I did; see below.  Where's your helpful answer, Crackers?

Answer (score 4):

You're failing to return a value. The method is declared to return a `double`, but you're falling off the end of your method without returning anything.

Answer (score 3):

I see too many problems with your code to bother answering your question.

Start by learning and following the Sun Java coding standards.

A good IDE will make errors like mismatched parentheses and failure to return a value a thing of the past.  Try IntelliJ; it's the best there is.

This will work much better than yours:

```
package cruft;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * StatisticsUtil has statistics utility methods
 * @author Michael
 * @link
 * @since 7/21/12 7:30 PM
 */
public class StatisticsUtil {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Double> values = new ArrayList<>();
        for (String arg : args) {
            values.add(Double.valueOf(arg));
        }
        System.out.println(String.format("median: %10.4f", getMedian(values)));
    }

    public static double getMedian(List<Double> values) {
        double median = 0.0;
        if (values != null) {
            int numValues = values.size();
            if (numValues > 0) {
                Collections.sort(values);
                if ((numValues%2) == 0) {
                    median = (values.get((numValues/2)-1)+values.get(numValues/2))/2.0;
                } else {
                    median = values.get(numValues/2);
                }
            }
        }
        return median;
    }

    public static double getMedian(double [] values) {
        double median = 0.0;
        if (values != null) {
            int numValues = values.length;
            if (numValues > 0) {
                Arrays.sort(values);
                if ((numValues%2) == 0) {
                    median = (values[(numValues/2)-1]+values[numValues/2])/2.0;
                } else {
                    median = values[numValues/2];
                }
            }
        }
        return median;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You declare the method "Median()" to return a double, but you don't return anything.